# With only the definition of a limit, can we determine what $l$ is in $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\ (x+t^3)=l$ without resorting to guessing $l$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Consider the limit

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\ (x+t^3)=l$$

This means $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0\ s.t.|x-a|<\delta \implies |x+t^3-l|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Assume we don't have prior knowledge of theorems about limits, we only know the above definition of what a limit is. In other words, assume this is a chapter in a book, about limits, and the only information presented so far is the definition of limits (this is the case for ch. 5 of Spivak's Calculus).

If we have a guess of what the limit $l$ is, we can verify if it is indeed the limit by subbing it into $(1)$. For example, if we guess $l=a+t^3$ then

$$|x-a|<\delta \implies |x+t^3-a-t^3|=|x-a|<\epsilon$$

$\forall \epsilon$ we can choose $\delta=\epsilon$ to make the statement above true always, proving that $l=a+t^3$ is true.

If we don't know what $l$ is, how can we find it without guessing a value?

Comment: I wouldn't call this "guessing", since all the functions are continuous, you can just substitute by the limit point. If you have no idea which the limit may be you can try studying some sequences or bounding your limit between two expressions that converge to a known limit.

Comment: I'm on ch. 5 of Spivak's Calculus. Limits is the first topic from Calculus that is introduced, simply with the definition in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. My question assumes that there is no knowledge of sequences or what a continuous function even is.

Comment: I don't really see the point in artificially limiting your options. In any case, if you substitute in the function by values "close" to your limit point that's usually a good limit candidate. That's exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: There is nothing circular or non-rigorous about making a guess, either based on information you "are not supposed to know yet" or just by random draw. Rigor comes in when you prove that your guess was correct or show that it was wrong. The definition of the limit is not about finding the limit. It is about how to prove that it is the limit.